# How to generate a specific design matrix in R?

Tags: r, glm, glmnet, model.matrix

I want to create a design matrix for use in the glmnet function. My predictors are player names; when player *i* plays a match against player *j* I want the row for that match to have a +1 in column *i* and a -1 in column *j*.

For example, if there are three players who all play each other, the design matrix should be as follows:

```
1 -1  0
1  0 -1 
0  1 -1
```

I've tried using model.matrix but I'm not sure how to create this specific design matrix - alternatively if there's a better format for this matrix that would also be helpful to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
num_players <- 4
matches <- t(combn(num_players, 2))
nr <- nrow(matches)

mtx <- matrix(0L, nrow = nr, ncol = num_players)
mtx[ cbind(seq_len(nr), matches[,1]) ] <- 1L
mtx[ cbind(seq_len(nr), matches[,2]) ] <- -1L
mtx
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   -1    0    0
# [2,]    1    0   -1    0
# [3,]    1    0    0   -1
# [4,]    0    1   -1    0
# [5,]    0    1    0   -1
# [6,]    0    0    1   -1
```

Comment: That's a nice concise solution, thank you! Is there no way of using a built-in function like model.matrix? I feel like R should be able to do something like this automatically.

Comment: I don't know of any. That doesn't mean it doesn't exist, I just haven't run into it.

Comment: It does seem that `model.matrix(..., contrasts=list(a="contr.sum"))` (in the help doc) is in the right direction, but ... idk, sorry.